# An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

My controller accepts parameters

```
public
void changeAvatar(
        @ApiParam(value = "A new avatar for the user", required = true)
        @RequestPart final MultipartFile avatar,
        BindingResult bindingResult
)
```

when sending a request to the controller, he throws me out

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: An Errors/BindingResult argument is expected to be declared immediately after the model attribute, the @RequestBody or the @RequestPart arguments to which they apply: public void com.web.web.controller.SettingsRestController.changeAvatar(org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile,org.springframework.validation.BindingResult) throws java.io.IOException
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Spring Framework Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments) :

> BindingResult
>
> Validation results for the command/form object data binding; this
>   argument must be declared immediately after the command/form object in
>   the controller method signature.

So, you can use `BindingResult` for getting binding-specific analysis only for your ***command/form object***.